# Is it possible to initialize values in ViewModel from values retrieved from proto DataStore?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

New to Jetpack Compose and Android development, I was simply trying to achieve these basic steps :

1. When ViewModel is initialized, retrieve user data stored in proto datastore just once.
2. Based on the values of user data, initialize other variables in the View Model. Perform operations on these variables to build an uiState.
3. Update that uiState based on UI interactions. Update user data in proto datastore on specific conditions.

However, apparently proto datastore only emits a flow, and synchronous operations are not advised in the documentation.

For now, I'm getting this flow in my ViewModel as follows :

`val userDataFlow : Flow<UserData> = appRepository.userDataFlow`

I know I can convert this to a StateFlow and collect this StateFlow in the UI layer, but I just need to retrieve the values stored in datastore during initialization, perform some operations on them, and possibly update them later based on how user interacts with UI.

Is such scenario possible ? This is a basic usecase, and I'm surprised it's quite difficult to apprehend for a beginner.

I'm currently wondering if I shouldn't just manually write user data to a simple `.json` file and fetch them during initialization.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: use the init block of viewmodel retrieve the data and you canuse flow operators and collec the data and build ui state

Comment: @Raghunandan : Thank you. So in the init block of the ViewModel, I would use something like `viewModelScope.launch { userData = userDataFlow.first() // then in init block initialize other variables from userData value }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, Yes you can do this in your viewModel without the `.json` file using the `combine` flow operator.

> `combine`: Returns a Flow whose values are generated with transform function by combining the most recently emitted values by each flow.

#### Example

```kotlin
val flow = flowOf(1, 2).onEach { delay(10) }
val flow2 = flowOf("a", "b", "c").onEach { delay(15) }
flow.combine(flow2) { i, s -> i.toString() + s }.collect {
    println(it) // Will print "1a 2a 2b 2c"
}
```

You can use `combine` operator to combine multiple cold flows and produce another flow (UiState most likely).

Using this, we can use this approach in viewModel:

```kotlin
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appRepository: AppRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    
    private val _userData : Flow<UserData> = appRepository.userDataFlow
    private val _userPreferences = appRepository.userPreferencesFlow // just an example
    private val _someOtherFlow = MutableStateFlow("")// could be mutable state flow u can change later based on UI / or another flow
    
    val uiState = combine(_userData, _userPreferences, _someOtherFlow) { userData, userPreferences, someOtherFlow ->
        buildUiState(userData, userPreferences, someOtherFlow)
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = /* */
    )
    
    private fun buildUiState(
        userData: UserData,
        preferences: UserPreferences
        someOtherFlow: SomeOtherFlow
    ): UiState {
        // Perform operations that u want and return the UiState
    }
    
    data class UiState(
        /* */
    )
}
```

The above solution offers flexibility and easy to change later according to your needs.

You can also look into other flow operators such as `map` and `transform` that could work for ur use case.

That's all upto to you.
Hope this helps.

## EDIT: (Reply to the comment)

If your case requires only the initial value from a value, then u can do something like this.

```kotlin
private val _userData = MutableStateFlow<UserData>(UserData(name = "")) // Define initial value here or null

private val _someOtherVariable = _userData.map {
   call any operation here
}

// Do for other variables like this as well if u want

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userData.update { appRepository.userDataFlow.first() }
        }
    }
```

The benifit of doing it like this would be that you would retain the state of data you obtained when u called `first()` on the flow. Second would be that you don't have to manually make sure assigning a value to the variables. Just define the operation for that variable in the `map` (or other flow operations) or a seperate function and call that function in the operator function (`map` in this case)

Once done with your data, I recommend creating the UiState using the combine operator since it ensures a new uiState every time any of the flow emits a new value.

```kotlin
    private val _userData = MutableStateFlow<UserData>(UserData(name = "")) 
    // Define initial value here or null

    private val _someOtherVariable = MutableStateFlow("")
    private val _anotherVariable = MutableStateFlow("")
    
    val uiState = _someOtherVariable.map { 
        UiState(someVariable = it)
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = null
    )

    val combinedUiState = _someOtherVariable.combine(_anotherVariable) { otherVariable, another ->
        UiState(otherVariable, _anotherVariable)
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = ""
    )

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userData.update { appRepository.userDataFlow.first() }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @[M ashal] : Thank you, however I need to make sure that during the initialization of my ViewModel, I just retrieve data once from the datastore. I was thinking about implementing the following : `{ userData = userDataFlow.first() // then in init block initialize other variables from userData value }` : what do you think about it ?

Comment: (following my previous comment) : Or once I created the uiState as you advised, I can simply get its value using `uiState.value` in the `init` block of my ViewModel, right ?

Comment: Hello @Elaws, Apologies for the late response. I've edited my comment at the bottom and u can refer to that for an answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Elaws You cannot call first() operator on a flow when defining a variable since it's a suspend function. The only place u can call first() is either a coroutine scope (viewModelScope) or a suspend function.